# About geocoding dependecies

Tags: position, flutter-dependencies, geocoding, pubspec, geolocator

Actualy I was trying out to run geoloactor app . But It shows an error like pubget is failed
on geocoding. What may be the problem like due to error in packages or anything else.
Please anyone suggest me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC9Iu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the screenshot provided, you created a Flutter project called `geocoding` and also depend on the existing `geocoding` package (see pubspec.yaml).

This now introduces a naming conflict and Dart cannot figure out if you want to import your own project into the file or if you want to import the `geocoding` package.

The solution would be to either:

1. Rename your project.
2. Remove the dependency on the `geocoding` package from your pubspec.yaml file.